# How to add files to newly created folder in ziparchive using php?

Tags: php, zip

[image]

As in the image above ,I have images that are organized in virtual folders(in mysql database but not real folders). I need to make the selected folder available for **download as zip**  .I was able to zip the images but how can we add subdirectory so as to add images to it  (i tried using  `addEmptyDir()` but couldn't figure out a way to add images into it! ). 
Is this really possible without creating the physical folder?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @dnagirl for your answer, but I was actually looking for a way to add files inside subfolders (maybe I was unable to make myself clear!)

discovered that zipArchive automatically creates folder if we give  '`path/to/filename`' instead of just '`filename`'

This is how I achieved it in case anybody may need it!

```
function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$img_localpath)
{
  $folder_path=WSP_AK_PLUGIN_DIR ."akTempFolder/";
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  if ($zip->open($folder_path.$archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )===TRUE) {
    //$zip->addEmptyDir('myimages');(this was what i thought would create folder!)
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        //$zip->addFile($img_localpath.'/'.$files, 'myfolder/'.$files);
        $zip->addFile($img_localpath.'/'.$files['fileName'],    $files['folder_path'].$files['fileName']);
    }
    $zip->close();
```

in above code `$files['folder_path']` will give the path to file where it will be created For eg `folder1/folder2/image1.jpg`

```
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($folder_path.$archive_file_name));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    if( file_exists($folder_path.$archive_file_name)) {
        ob_clean();
        readfile($folder_path.$archive_file_name);
    }
    unlink($folder_path.$archive_file_name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - I was missing ob_clean() and wondering why I kept getting "Unexpected end of Archive" errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the "files" you want to add to your zip directory are stored in a db as strings, you could use [`ZipArchive::addFromString`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php). If the db stores pointers to actual files use [`ZipArchive::addFile`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php)

Comment: No, the directory content are images

Comment: @DipeshKc: images are either files or binary strings. So one of the two functions I mentioned should work for you.